# How to display a map Frame above PanoramaGL-Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, osmdroid, panoramas

I use the PanoramaGL Library (https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/) to display spheric 360° Images.

What  I want:
The top half of the screen should contain a OSMdroid-Map (https://osmdroid.net/) and the bottom half shows panoramic images with PanoramaGL like this:

[image]

Problems:
You create panoramic Views in PanoramaGL using the class PLView which extends Activity.

If you show a panoramic image it always occupies the whole screen, and I see no way to change the layout. As soon as I try to define any xml-Layout, the panoramic image does not show up anymore.

My current code, where the map-part is commented out, so that only the panoramic image is displayed:

```
package com.example.campusnav;
//lots of imports...
public class MainActivity extends PLView {

private MapView mMapView;
private MapController mMapController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
    mMapController.setZoom(13);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(52.432846, 8.369147);
    mMapController.setCenter(startPoint);*/

    PLSpherical2Panorama panorama = new PLSpherical2Panorama();
    panorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.raw.p_1), false));
    this.setPanorama(panorama);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions how to work around this problem? Is there a way to display two seperate activities arranged in a vertical layout?

Comment: osmdroid.net is NOT the osmdroid map library.  https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid is the correct url. Have your tried using fragments?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can display both Panorama and map together

1. Extend your activity from PLView
2. XML

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rl_streetview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#00FF40" >
   </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rl_mapview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/rl_streetview"
       android:layout_margin="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" >

       <fragment
           android:id="@+id/location_map"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. Activity

   ```
   @Override
       protected View onContentViewCreated(View contentView) {
           ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
           rl_streetview = (RelativeLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.rl_streetview);
           rl_mapview = (RelativeLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.rl_mapview);
   ```

   }